# How can I make the Tab Drop Down In Sql Server Management Studio display more of the File Names

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Am I the only person annoyed by this?  I don't even know what proc I'm clicking on if the file names have the same prefix, or are longer than the context window width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the tab dropdown, as well as the tab names themselves, annoying. You can't widen either of them.

It helps to save each script to a file, even if only temporarily. I work in an environment where I need to save each script I write. I can see the file names if I hover over each tab. Not perfect, but it helps.

If you're running SSMS 2008 (or even just SSMS Express 2008), you can change certain property settings so that only certain things are shown in each tab: the current server, the current database, the filename, etc. If you only work in a single database, for instance, you could switch off everything except the filename.

But unless any of these suggestions help, there's really no way around those stupid tabs.

Answer (score 1):

connect is garbage, they dont do anything

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to make it any bigger.

I find this greatly annoying as well.  There are a couple of connect items open about this.